# Figuring out what triggered digest cycle

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

my app has some function expressions being called in an infinite loop and I am trying to figure out what is triggering the digest. i've nailed it down to something being outside of the current view so it's more difficult to track down.

any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean by outside of the current view?

Comment: i'm using ui-router and show different views based on what part of the system the user wants to see. i created a view with just a simple expression and it still gets called in a loop. im thinking maybe it has to do with a third-party directive or something.